# SQL - Return "True" if a customer purchased product A, and "False" otherwise

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL table with a list of customer IDs, Invoices, Products they have purchased (Product A, Product B..), etc..

I need to write a query that returns two columns - one for the list of existing customers and another boolean column which says "True" if the customer purchased product A, and false otherwise.

How do I do that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select customerid,
       max(case when productid = 'A' then 1 else 0 end)
from a
group by customerid;
```

Note:  This uses `1` for "true" and `0` for "false".  If you want strings, you can use:

```
select customerid,
       max(case when productid = 'A' then 'True' else 'False' end)
from a
group by customerid;
```